# Why are my template variables allegedly missing from my YQL query?

Tags: environment-variables, yql, api-key, uritemplate

I'm trying to hide an API key within a YQL query. To do so, I've tried following [this post](http://nagiworld.net/2010/03/keeping-secrets-safe-with-yql-storage) (also explained by the same author [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120226165740/https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/How-to-hide-my-API-Key/1285953327000-2a031d3e-5c3a-35e4-ac01-27abd7e92bd8/)). When I try and run a query using the URI template, I get the following warning returned:

```
"warning": "Missing template variables (BungieAPIKey)"
```

Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Save the API key within `yql.storage.admin` by running `insert into yql.storage.admin (value) values ("set BungieAPIKey='YOUR_KEY' on uritemplate;")`
2. Load the environment into the console using the returned execute key (`https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?env=store://XXXXXXXXXX`)
3. Run `select * from json where url in (select url from uritemplate where template='http://bungie.net/videos/{BungieAPIKey}/{user}/{page}'  and user='foo' and page='bar')`

Here is the JSON that is returned:

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 0,
  "created": "2015-01-13T16:58:57Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "warning": "Missing template variables (BungieAPIKey)",
   "redirect": {
    "from": "http://bungie.net/videos//foo/bar",
    "status": "301",
    "content": "http://www.bungie.net/videos/foo/bar"
   },
   "url": {
    "execution-start-time": "0",
    "execution-stop-time": "573",
    "execution-time": "573",
    "http-status-code": "404",
    "http-status-message": "Not Found",
    "content": "http://bungie.net/videos//foo/bar"
   },
   "error": "Invalid JSON document http://bungie.net/videos//foo/bar",
   "user-time": "574",
   "service-time": "573",
   "build-version": "0.2.212"
  },
  "results": null
 }
}
```

In an attempt to narrow down the issue, I tried the following query in a clean YQL console (no env set):

```
set BungieAPIKey='YOUR_KEY' on uritemplate;
select url from uritemplate where template='http://bungie.net/videos/{BungieAPIKey}/'
```

[Running this](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=set+BungieAPIKey%3D'YOUR_KEY'+on+uritemplate%3B%0Aselect+url+from+uritemplate+where+template%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fbungie.net%2Fvideos%2F%7BBungieAPIKey%7D%2F') gives me the same warning. **Why aren't my template variables pulling from what I have set as environment variables?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like set x='y' on uritemplate is not being honored for some reason. 
In the absence of this, you have the option of having a custom table which accepts a typed parameter say apiKey. You could then have the following:

```
 use 'http://location-of-custom-table' as tablename;
 set apiKey='foo' on tablename;
 select * from tablename;
```

In the above case, the apiKey would be passed in to the custom table and you can append it in javascript and create your url.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your solution will have to work for now, I'll try and do some further investigation for why SET isn't cooperating.